# TFS Test - mstest log output - final test results

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, mstest

A couple of days ago our vs2012 mstest started producing two logs of test results in the one session, the initial "Results Top Level Tests" then Final Test Results:" "Results Top Level Tests" 
As we parse the file, naturally we came undone with two lots of results.

> > Why is their two lots of results and - or how was this triggered ?
> >     What is "Final Test Results" about?
> >     (the console output from mstest is piped to a file)
> >     Thanks

Comment: How did you run the tests? What about running the test within visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, the issue should be caused by the test cases or the test processes which have something wrong. And the "`Final Test Results`" will appear there.

Simply say, when the message "`Final Test Results`" appears, that means maybe there are something wrong with the configuration of your test project or test processes.

So, please check and debug the test cases, processes, environments etc...
Firstly make sure the tests running without any error within local Visual Studio.

Reference:

- [MSTest hangs when used from command line](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af1ec6f3-4582-4f6c-9687-dd6479f86496/mstest-hangs-when-used-from-command-line?forum=vststest)
- [MSTest.exe command-line options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Using%20MSTest%20Options)